# Use digitalRead function at setup

Tags: debugging, arduino

Is it possible to use `digitalRead()` function on Arduino setup to check if a circuit is opened or closed and act as a physical DEBUG flag?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Do a `pinmode()` first - maybe you need to set the pull-up. Maybe wait a tiny bit for the levels to settle down, since you probably just turned it on. Then you can read the pin with `digitalRead()`.